# Why do I get "ImportError: No module named pdb"

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pdb

I am running a python virtualenv in OS X.

I have installed pdb using pip in the virtualenv.

But when I run pdb, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/pdb", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pdb==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pdb')()
  File "/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2431, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2147, in load
    ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named pdb
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What did you expect to install here; the [*Password database*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdb) or the standard library [debugger module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)?

The stdlib debugger doesn't need installing, but it has no command line interface of its own. You *can* specify the module on the `python` command line with the `-m` switch to set up post mortem debugging; see the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html):

```
python -m pdb yourscript.py
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with:

```
ImportError: No module named pdb
```

and fixed it with changing the order of imports.
In my script the order was:

```
import pdb
import os
import shutil
```

now its

```
import os
import shutil
import pdb
```

Its working now.